# Xpages - Java library - error in NotesFactory.CreateSession

Tags: xpages

first, Extension Library is not yet available for some servers. I want to compare document count in all replicas of a db. I want to display the same in web. So I am looping through catalog.nsf entries. Here is the code. Problem is, it's not able to create session. Here goes the code:

```
package com.apse.replication;
import java.util.*;
import lotus.domino.*;

/**
 * @author Arun Agnihotri
 *
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public class ReplicationCountMismatches
{
    Session s = null;
    Database catDb = null;
    View catView = null;
    Document catDoc = null;
    DocumentCollection catCol = null;
    Vector v;
    String key;

    //hashmap object to hold the database replica id as key and document count as value
    Hashtable<String, Integer> dbTable = new Hashtable<String, Integer>();

    //array to hold server names
    String serverNames[] = {"Server1","Serevr2","Server3"};

    public DocumentCollection GetMismatchedReplicas(){

    //we'll loop through catalog database of every server and update the hashmap
    try{

        for (int i=0;i<serverNames.length;i++){
            s = NotesFactory.createSession(); //this is WHERE I RECEIVE ERROR
            catDb = s.getDatabase(serverNames[i], "catalog.nsf");
            catView = catDb.getView("Applications\\By Title");
            catDoc = catView.getFirstDocument();

            while(catDoc!=null){
                v = s.evaluate("@Text(ReplicaID;\"*\")", catDoc);
                key=v.firstElement().toString();
                if (i==0){
                    //first catalog being scanned.. put all key-value pairs in HashTable
                    dbTable.put(key, catDoc.getItemValueInteger("DbNumDocuments"));
                }
                else{
                    if (!dbTable.containsKey(key)){
                        dbTable.put(key, catDoc.getItemValueInteger("DbNumDocuments"));
                    }
                    else{
                        if ((Integer) dbTable.get(key) != catDoc.getItemValueInteger("DbNumDocuments")){
                            catCol.addDocument(catDoc); 
                        }
                    }
                }
                catDoc = catView.getNextDocument(catDoc);
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return catCol;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Jsf session when your Java code runs in XPages context.

```
import com.ibm.xsp.extlib.util.ExtLibUtil;
...
Session s = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentSession();
```

If the server your code will be executed on doesn't have the ExtLibUtil you can create your own JsfUtil library like shown [here](http://www.mindoo.com/web/blog.nsf/dx/18.07.2009191738KLENAL.htm?opendocument&comments).